# Set div to hidden, then visible after time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles, visibility

I'm trying to have a yellow square appear on a black background after X amount of time (perhaps even after a random amount of time, but for now let's just do fixed time).

```js
function initialSetup() {
  if (document.getElementById("yellow") != null) {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'visible'", 2000);
  }
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow" class="box yellow"></div>
```

This code should hide the yellow square initially, then reveal it after 2 seconds. But it does not work. It also does not work when I try to use a button to initiate the javascript function. I've looked at other examples and compared my code to theirs and it seems like it should work!

https://jsfiddle.net/xxPoLyGLoTxx/51spg8d1/

Comment: Use a function instead of a string inside setTimeout. Also, you're not calling initialSetup(); inside the fiddle.

Comment: FYI, if you go with fixed time, this effect can be achieve using pure CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/867z211y/

Comment: Very cool Quangdao Nguyen about the CSS trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly your syntax is missing a `}`. Secondly, to follow best practice you should provide `setTimeout` with a function reference. Your current code will be invoked via `eval()` which should be avoided at all costs. Thirdly, you need to use `backgroundColor`, not `color`, to set the element background. Lastly, you don't call `intitialSetup()` anywhere. With those issues in mind, try this:

```js
function initialSetup() {
  if (document.getElementById("yellow") != null) {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('yellow').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
    }, 2000);
  }
}

initialSetup();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow" class="box yellow"></div>
```

Note that with this logic you're not making the yellow `div` hidden - as your title implies. It's only not immediately obvious as you've changed its background colour to match the black background of the `body`. If you want to make the element completely invisible, use the `display` property. You can also set it in CSS to avoid a FOUC when the page loads:

```js
function initialSetup() {
  if (document.getElementById("yellow") != null) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('yellow').style.display = 'block';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

initialSetup();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow" class="box yellow"></div>
```

Finally, here's a jQuery implementation of the above as you've tagged the question as such:

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#yellow').show()
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yellow" class="box yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as does the keyframes CSS trick up above. So it appears that I just needed to call the function (which I thought was done automatically onload in Jsfiddle, but guess not) and then have another function inside setTimeout instead of a string. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**setTimeout() Syntax**

The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function actually expects a function to be passed to it as opposed to a string :

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}, 2000);
```

Additionally, instead of hiding it through Javascript, you might consider just applying a CSS style to handle it being hidden by default (i.e. `display: none`) and then simply  showing it within the body of your `setTimeout()` function call.

**Example**

[image]

```js
function initialSetup() {
  if (document.getElementById("yellow") != null) {
    document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

initialSetup();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="yellow" class="box yellow"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function initialSetup() {
            if (document.getElementById("yellow") !== null) {
                document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility = 'visible';
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
```