# Make a Div [Message] FadeIn and Fadeout every time (regularly appear for some time and disappear again)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how a message (div) can appear for a duration of two minutes in my website (every 15 minutes). Any (script) or help is appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: As a first step step I'd recommend existing questions about how to show/hide div elements after some time. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228423/set-div-to-hidden-then-visible-after-time-delay

Comment: Dear Paulie, i've searched everywhere before posting but couldn't find the solution to it. It is my first time to ever post in here...i'm a noob in javascript, therefore i don't see how i can start or attempt coding the function i need and post it! Don't be harsh on beginners and close the post like that...that's not very kind! I'm glad that others thought differently and helped instead of complaining!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something along these lines will work. You'll need a html element with `id=myDiv` and a css rule which makes `myDiv` hidden unless it has the `visible` class enabled on it. You should change the interval numbers to smaller numbers to test it.

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('myDiv').classList.add('visible');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myDiv').classList.remove('visible');
    },1000*60*2) //turn off after 2 minutes
},1000*60*15) //turn on after 15 minutes
```

CSS will handle the 'fading' part like so:

```
#myDiv{ 
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    transition:opacity 1s;
}
#myDiv.visible{ 
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:all;
}
```